# Transformation of a simple logic statement

Tags: functions, programming, logic

I'm designing a logic circuit and I was wondering if the following two things are equivalent:

(x <= y) and (x < (y + 1))

I can't think of any set of numbers that would make these two things not equivalent. Only real integers are allowed. Thank you.

Comment: Why wont you just test it in Mathematica?

Comment: `Implies[(x <= y) , (x < (y + 1))] // Simplify`

Comment: Have a look at ForALL as well.

Comment: @rasher Could you to justify your claim? I'm affraid that is an artifact of the system even though that is true, because `Simplify` is not a substitute for `Resolve`.

Comment: @Artes: perhaps I'm mistaken, seem to recall resolve/reduce part of simplify under the covers.

Comment: @rasher What do you mean??? Shouldn't `Simplify[Implies[(x <= y) && x > 0, (x <= 2 y)]]` yield `True`? It doesn't. While this works `Resolve@ForAll[{x, y}, Implies[(x <= y) && x > 0, (x <= 2 y)]]`.

Comment: This easily provable by hand. Since we know that $x \le y$ and we know that $y < y + 1$, then we can state that $x \le y < y + 1$, or more succinctly, $x < y + 1$. Nothing more is needed. But, [Artes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45038/52) provides a nice waving of proving it in _Mathematica_.

Comment: @rcollyer's comment preceding proves only the easy half of what I presume is an intended logical equivalence: for all integers `x` and `y`, $x \leq y \Leftrightarrow x < y+1$.

Answer (score 1):

In *Mathematica*:

```
    Reduce[ForAll[{x, y}, x <= y \[Equivalent] x < y + 1], Integers]
(* True *)
```

or:

```
    Resolve[ForAll[{x, y}, x <= y \[Equivalent] x < y + 1], Integers]
(* True *)
```

For a mathematical proof, the direct implication $x \leq y \Rightarrow x < y+1$ has the trivial proof noted by @rcollyer in a comment. The converse implication $x < y + 1 \Rightarrow x<=y$ is a consequence of the proposition that, for every integer $y$, there is no integer strictly between $y$ and $y + 1$. The proof of that reduces to the case of nonnegative $y$, and then one may argue from the axioms for the natural numbers.